# Add whitespace to string at specific places

Tags: c++, string, binary, whitespace, range-v3

I have a string "00000000000000000000010011010010". I want to add a whitespace after every eighth char to make it represent a 32 bit integer. For example: "00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010". What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Just [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) the space in a loop until the end of the string? Remember that inserting a character will change the length.

Comment: Do you really want to put spaces in the string, or do you want to only display the string with those spaces in it?

Comment: Note that creating a new string will be simpler than modifyng current string in-place

Comment: Nice question - here cigiens solution for IBANs https://godbolt.org/z/roq4Es

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the range-v3 library, the code is quite simple to understand:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto res = s | views::chunk(8) | views::join(' ') | to<std::string>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nnH9uz).

Comment: This is so neat! Is this kind of ranges API intended to be standard as of C++20?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. `chunk` doesn't appear to be available in c++20 though `join` is. You can still write it yourself without *too much* effort :)

Comment: Nice, an excellent new C++ feature that allows writing more functional-style code similar to that of other modern languages such as Swift.

Comment: @cigien, this is awesome! what are those `|`? pipes? how can I find more information about this?

Comment: @djacob It's just the bitwise operator :) But yes, the operator is overloaded for ranges, to have unix pipe like semantics. You can find c++20 [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) here, but there are some nice youtube videos that you can watch as well.

Comment: Thanks @cigien! I watched the creator's cppcon talk. Mind blowing!

Comment: `ranges::to` also missed the C++20 boat, but it will be there for '23, and you can use the one in range-v3 until then.

Answer (score 0):

#### Construct a new whitespace-delimited string

As insertions are a bit expensive, you may want to simply construct a new string and fill it from the original, adding spaces as appropriate after every substring of eight characters (save for the final substring).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string chunked(const std::string& s,
                    const std::size_t chunk_size = 8U,
                    const char delimiter = ' ') {
    std::string result;
    const auto s_size = s.size();
    result.reserve(s_size + (s_size / chunk_size));

    for (std::size_t i = 0U; i < s_size; i += chunk_size) {
        result += s.substr(i, chunk_size);
        if (i + chunk_size < s_size) { 
            result += delimiter; 
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << chunked({"00000000000000000000010011010010"}); 
      // 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010

    return 0;
}
```

#### Print the existing string as whitespace-delimited chunks

Alternatively, your use case may be to simply print the string as whitespace-separated 8-character chunks:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printAsChunks(const std::string& s, 
                   const std::size_t chunk_size = 8U) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0U; i < s.size(); i += chunk_size) {
        std::cout << s.substr(i, chunk_size) 
            << ((i + chunk_size < s.size()) ? " " : "");
    }
}

int main() {
    printAsChunks("00000000000000000000010011010010");
        // 00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010
    return 0;
}
```